# free() runtime error while working with structure pointer arrays

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free, realloc

Hello i have been struggling with my code for a while and finally found that the free() funtion is the cause. I think i am missing something about the details of how free() works.

> **My output is :**

```
test test test test test 
ID: 200
RELEASE YEAR: 2006


ID: 201
RELEASE YEAR: 2006


ID: 202
RELEASE YEAR: 2006


ID: 203
RELEASE YEAR: 2006


ID: 204
RELEASE YEAR: 2006


AB
```

> **Edit : Added the full code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000                                        //Do not edit this macro.

typedef struct{
    int film_id;
    char title[255];
    char description[1023];
    unsigned int release_year;
    char rental_duration;
    float rental_rate;
    unsigned char length;
    float replacement_cost;
    char rating[10];
    char last_update[30];
} RECORD_t, *RECORD;                                    //Do not edit this struct.


RECORD *find_by_year(int release_year, RECORD film_array, int start, int end,int *found);


int main(){
    RECORD rec = (RECORD)malloc(sizeof(RECORD_t)*MAX);  //Do not edit this line.
    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "rb");               //Do not edit this line.
    if (file == NULL) {                                 //Do not edit this line.
        printf("Cannot open the file.\n");              //Do not edit this line.
        exit(0);                                        //Do not edit this line.
    }                                                   //Do not edit this line.
    fread(rec, sizeof(RECORD_t)*MAX, 1, file);          //Do not edit this line.
    fclose(file);                                       //Do not edit this line.


    int i,test;
    RECORD *rec_arr;

    rec_arr=find_by_year(2006,rec,200,203,&test);
    for(i=0;i<test;i++){
            printf("ID: %d\n", rec_arr[i]->film_id);
            printf("RELEASE YEAR: %d\n", rec_arr[i]->release_year);
            printf("\n\n");
            fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("A");
                fflush(stdout);

//  file = fopen("data.txt", "wb");                     //Do not edit this line.
//  fwrite(rec, sizeof(RECORD_t)*MAX, 1, file);         //Do not edit this line.
//  fclose(file);                                       //Do not edit this line.
    free(rec);                                          //Do not edit this line.


    printf("B");
    fflush(stdout);

    free(rec_arr);

printf("C");
    fflush(stdout);

    return 1;                                           //Do not edit this line.
}

RECORD *find_by_year(int release_year, RECORD film_array, int start, int end,int *found) {

    RECORD *rec_arr=malloc(sizeof(RECORD)*1);
    RECORD *narray;//for realloc check
    int size=1,i,j;
    start--;
    if(rec_arr==NULL){//if malloc fails
        printf("MALLOC FAILED find_by_year returning NULL\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return NULL;
    }

    for(i=start;i<=end;i++){
        if(film_array[i].release_year==release_year){
            rec_arr[size-1]=&film_array[i];
            size++;
            narray=realloc(rec_arr,size);//increment the size by 1


            //ERROR HANDLING
            if(narray==NULL){//if realloc fails
                printf("INNER REALLOC FAILED find_by_year");
                fflush(stdout);
                narray =malloc(sizeof(RECORD) * size);

                if(narray==NULL){ //if malloc fails
                    printf("INNER MALLOC ALSO FAILED find_by_year returning NULL\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    return NULL;
                }

                for(j=1;j<size;j++){//copy
                    narray[size-1]=rec_arr[size-1];
                    free(rec_arr);
                }
            }
            printf("test ");
            fflush(stdout);

            rec_arr=narray;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    *found=size-1;


    if(size==1)//if not found anything
        return NULL;

    return rec_arr;
}
```

From the results of debugging free(rec_arr) fails everytime what could be the problem here. I cropped the code and i am almost sure that the cropped parts are working from the debugging.

Comment: Your example cannot be compiled! Try to edit it.

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  . There's a bug in a part of the code you didn't show . The design of `find_by_year` is suspicious as it provides no way for the caller to know how many items are returned

Comment: @M.M okay here is the full code if you want to take a look

Comment: @MustafaÇığGökpınar can you also provide a sample of `data.txt` ?

Comment: Does your file contains exactly 1000 records? if not you are overflowing the data or accessing out of bounds in the function. I suggest to use `ftell` divided by `sizeof(RECORD_t)` to get the number of records instead of using a magic number like 1000

Comment: @DavidRanieri unfortunately there are exactly 1000 movies in the data. I know it sounds ridiculous.

Comment: @DavidRanieri and/or check the return value of `fread`.  It's suspicious that a `.txt` file is supposedly containing binary representations of floating point (and structure padding)

Comment: @MustafaÇığGökpınar could you post just the first of the 1000 movies from the file? (and then we can assume the other rows are similar).

Comment: @M.M i can do that do you want the binary form or the printfed form.

Comment: binary form preferably (if you can put it in some format that will display, e.g. a `hexdump`)

Comment: @M.M yes it still does :(.I am starting to think that the problem is my eclipse+CDT.

Comment: If this code was in the editor, check you saved the file?

Comment: what does the runtime error look like?

Comment: @M.M Pls see the edit.The code compiles and prints these values actually but it crashes just before the free as we can see from the AB debug printfs.

Comment: BTW I would not recommend the code block you start with "ERROR HANDLING" , it would be better to just return failure at that point or abort the program (recovering from out-of-memory is an advanced topic and the recovery code is most likely to also fail itself) . But that is not the cause of the problem

Comment: oh, I see the problem now

Comment: @M.M oh wow for real now i am excited :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
narray=realloc(rec_arr,size);//increment the size by 1
```

The second argument to `realloc` should be the number of bytes, not the number of records. You should multiply `size` by `sizeof(RECORD)` .

---

Here's some general recommendations about the rest of the code:

- I suggest just aborting in the `if(narray=NULL)` case. That code will almost never happen anyway , and probably will fail anyway even if it does enter.  Recovering from out-of-memory is an advanced topic (especially taking into account that modern operating systems overcommit).
- You mentioned using Eclipse+CDT -- you should be able to step through the code in the debugger instead of having to use printf debugging statements.
- It would be good to check for `rec` being `NULL` on the first line of main,  and also check the return value of `find_by_year` -- if it returns NULL then you don't want to go on to do the `i` loop. Your function does not set `*found` in the case of returning `NULL`, sometimes, so the caller has to do the null check before using the record count.
- I don't really agree with the other suggestion to change the realloc strategy. Keeping the code simple to read is not a bad plan , either for beginners or experts.  And I doubt it is really inefficient as modern operating systems have a minimum allocation size so the realloc calls will basically be doing nothing unless your search returns more than say 1000 records.

Comment: OH THANK YOU!. I have been spending too much time and didn't even noticed that.

Comment: @MustafaÇığGökpınar OK, I added some more suggestions

Comment: @M.M good catch and good advices! and I agree, using `realloc` even with the cost of restoring the previous data is most of the times preferable than memory fragmentation, but in this case (the origin was there and it was computable beforehand) I will prefer a single allocation

Comment: @DavidRanieri it probably is a single allocation -- say the OS provides a min size 4K block to the program, then the realloc call will just be adjusting the size used from 4, then 8, then 12 etc. , not actually requesting any more memory from the OS.  I suspect it might be slower to pass over the data twice than to stick with the current code, if we're not returning thousands of records (which are pointers so you get lots of them in that 4K block) .  If we look towards scaling up then I'd still tend to favour a single read pass but with a larger block strategy as the first attempt

Comment: @M.M that's a very interesting point, developing a kind of emulation of std::vector using `realloc` growing by a factor of 2 I appreciated that the memory address always changes (at least on gcc under Debian and using different levels of optimization)

Comment: @DavidRanieri C++ allocators don't support realloc, they always obtain a new block and free the old . There has been much debate over whether this was a good idea or not... the issue is that C++ objects might not be trivially relocatable (e.g. they may contain a pointer to themself) so having an unpredictable movement would spoil things.  I think the library implementor would be allowed to use a realloc for a vector of trivially relocatable objects with default allocator under the as-if rule -- but that discussion would exceed the space in comments!

Comment: @M.M, I mean in C the address returned by `realloc` was always (really allways) different than the previous call to `realloc`, that means that the data must be copied to the new block, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes; I guess you could dig into the libc implementation of realloc to see how any particular one works

Answer (score 2):

The main thing wrong with your code is the approach.  Repeatedly incrementing the size of an array by one using `realloc()` is horrifically inefficient.  Instead, just do one pass over the data to check how many records match, then allocate the entire storage at once and do a second pass to populate it.  Or, allocate an array as large as all the records, populate just the part you need, and don't worry about the "wasted" memory because it probably doesn't matter.

Either of the above approaches will result in much simpler code with fewer bugs.

Comment: Inefficient use of realloc has nothing to do with a runtime error due to `free()` -- this should be  acomment at best

Comment: @M.M  we can not see why it fails because 1) the code doesn't compile and 2) the OP is ommiting the critical part: _//reading data from a txt file_, furthermore John is giving a good advice maybe too long to be a comment, it looks like a good answer to me

Comment: @DavidRanieri The question is why `free()` crashes , and this "answer" does not address that question at all.  The fact that the question text is rubbish doesn't change that . Answers are for an answer to the question, not general advice.

Comment: @M.M: Unlike you, I am trying to help OP by addressing what may be the root cause of their problems.

Comment: @JohnZwinck thanks for the advice thats way more efficient .However as we are learning realloc and malloc our lecturers requested us to approch the problem like this.

Comment: @JohnZwinck it's not the root cause of the problem . You could modify this function to use a smarter realloc strategy (which probably will not involve "simpler code") and that will not fix the heap corruption that's occuring elsewhere in the program (or in the "real code" as we now find out that the code posted wasn't even the real code).